# Getting a UI to be adaptive for iPhone and iPad

Tags: xamarin.ios, uistoryboard, adaptive-layout

I'm working on a xamarin app and the goal is to have the UI be adaptive for both phone and tablet and so far it seems Android has a far easier way to achieve this. I'm reading [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/user-interface/designer/designer-auto-layout) article on the matter and it honestly don't make a lick of sense.

All I want is to have everything grow in portion to the view as it gets bigger because of screen size (like android does), every time I try to do it it just anchors the control to the right and it just drags it to the right.

I mainly just need some a simple explanation on how I can have everything grow with the view.

Comment: Well, in my opinion, `autoLayout` is more popular and easier to design UI between different device sizes. It's a `Relative layout`.

Comment: I ended up going that way which was much nicer and easier to understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out, After some deep breathing I saw what I was missing when I was reading the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/user-interface/ios-ui/layout-options).

for me, I wanted to use the autosize options, which let me anchor it how I wanted it to and it correctly scales for me now.